# Chrome Extension Javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write Chrome Extension in pure javascript to fetch a collection of nodes and make some changes to it. So, I started off with:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("testclass");    
console.log(list);           //1
console.log(list.length);    //2
console.log(list[0]);        //3
```

The output for this comes up as:

```
1. An object [item:function, namedItem:function], which has all the elements and a length: <number of elements> and __proto___: HTMLCollection (As Expected)
2. 0
3. undefined
```

The same thing, which I give in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mukilr/dj1mg1ct/), I get proper outputs:

```
1. HTMLCollection object with all elements and length: <no of elements> and __proto__: HTMLCollection
2. <no of elements>
3. First Element
```

Why am I unable to iterate when the javascript used is them same? Is there something else to do when we are using a Chrome extension?'

Heres my manifest.json in case it helps:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Something",
  "description": "Something something...",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "notifications",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/"
    ],

  "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["https://*","http://*"],
        "js": ["testscript.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["samplejs.js"],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

My javascript code is in `testscript.js`

Comment: From where you trying to fetch the collection?

Comment: Im writing a chrome extension with content_scripts to ultimately modify contents of the DOM of any page.

Comment: Ok, so the above code is from `testscript.js`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @MklRjv Please: 1) roll back your edit, 2) post your answer as an answer

Comment: Also, for pure JS the solution is to wait on `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. The problem was that the DOM was not getting loaded fully, hence my script which executed before DOM got loaded, could not fetch data properly is what I am guessing.

I tried using

```
document.onload=function(){}
```

and

```
window.onload=function(){}
```

window.onload had trouble fetching the output, and document.onload never triggered at all.

So, tried using a delay:

```
setTimeout(function(){
      <javascript code>
},3000);
```

And this works fine. Not sure if its the best method.

As an alternative, added jquery to the extension and used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      <javascript code>
});
```

And this works even better.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did some modifications in your `manifest` file and it worked for me. Here is the updated version:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Something",
  "description": "Something something...",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "notifications",
    "http://*/",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
    "js": ["testscript.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["samplejs.js"],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

I have changed the `permissions` and `matches` sections.

Comment: Made changes as suggested, but getting the same result. :-(

Comment: Dunno if it will help, but, when checking through Developer Tools, the divs are listed in the name itself, as in jsfiddle [div.testclass,div.testclass,div.testclass,div.testclass, item:function,namedItem:function], but through injected code, [item:function, namedItem:function] only is shown.

Comment: I have uploaded the extension here: https://www.sendspace.com/file/hk0s2m. Just download it, unzip and load into chrome as `unpacked extension`. Then go to this page (this question's page) and then open up the `console`. I used `default` class instead of `testclass`.

Comment: It works fine for me, first prints the HTMLCollection with correct results, then the number and after it the first element.

Comment: Found a solution, updated question. Thanks for your help though. +1..:-)